# Module exports .js file is missing when doing jspm install

Tags: jspm, systemjs

I'm finding it pretty hard to wrap my head around the jspm/systemjs ecosystem sometimes, but today I found a workaround to the following problem.

I needed to be able to do something like this:

```
import 'bootstrap'
import 'ifightcrime/bootstrap-growl'
```

Problem is that when I do jspm install -y github/ifightcrime/bootstrap-growl@1.1.0 only the folder (and files inside of course) jspm_packages/ifightcrime/bootstrap-growl@1.1.0 is created, but the bootstrap-growl@1.1.0.js which is responsisble for the module.exports is missing.

So when I manually add that in jspm_packages/ifightcrime/ like this:

```
// bootstrap-growl@1.1.0.js
module.exports = require("github:ifightcrime/bootstrap-growl@1.1.0/jquery.bootstrap-growl");
```

I can do the import in my code.

But how would I make sure this file is created automatically when other people do a jspm-install? This file was created manually by me, so it wouldn't be working for them, without also doing this.

Comment: We're experiencing the same issue. Did you ever figure the fix?